How to open Screen Flow from LWC as Modal or Popup in Community
Hello Salesforce Ohana,
I am able to access flow from lwc but i am unable to find any documentation for how to open screen flow as modal or popup. I tried adding flow inside Modal but still it is not opening as Modal.
Any suggestions or workaround or documentation would be really helpful.
<template>
<lightning-flow flow-name=‘xyz’></lightning-flow> 
</template>

Thanks in advance.

Can you please share your code snippets please?

It is straight forward on click of button i want to open Screen flow as Popup. 

You can utilize the lightning/modal module provided by the salesforce.
It provides the LightningModal component to create a modal window on top of the current app window.
You can create a separate HTML file using template and open it from the parent LWC component using .open() method.
Please refer to this link.
